# VS Code C++ "error: ‘filesystem’ is not a namespace-name"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I'm trying to run some very simple code from the accepted answer for this question in VS Code: [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)

However, VS Code keeps giving me errors with the filesystem library such as follows:

```
error: ‘filesystem’ is not a namespace-name
   32 | namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. I checked my version of GCC and it's listed as 9.3.0. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you enable c++17? It's probably not the default.

Comment: I believe [https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14) says that c++14 is the default ***GCC has full support for the of the 2014 C++ standard.

This mode is the default in GCC 6.1 up until GCC 10 (including);***

Comment: @drescherjm Where would I enable that? In my c_cpp_properties.json file I have "cppStandard" set to gnu++17, is that correct?

Comment: Ah, okay. So the solution is that I need a newer version of GCC?

Comment: `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json`. `c_cpp_properties.json` is for intellisense while `tasks.json` is about building.

Comment: @drescherjm I see, thank you! I actually ended up being able to fix the issue by adding the C++ 17 standard to my cmake file, which I didn't think about until your answer, so thanks!

Comment: I did not know you were using CMake.